# Is it true that every closed ideal $J$ of $ A \otimes_hB$ is of the form $\epsilon^{-1}(I)$ for some closed ideal $I$ of $A \otimes_\text{min} B$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras. It is known that the  map $\epsilon:A \otimes_h B \to A \otimes_\text{min} B$ is continuous and injective.

> Is it true that every closed ideal $J$ of $ A \otimes_hB$ is of the form $\epsilon^{-1}(I)$ for some closed ideal $I$ of $A \otimes_\text{min} B$.

Setting $I= \overline{\epsilon(J)}$ works?

P.S: Copy of the same question on MO can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416342/is-it-true-that-every-closed-ideal-j-of-a-otimes-hb-is-of-the-form-epsil).